# Remotely hosted code replacement in Manifest V3

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, manifest.json

I previously had a content script that fetched the code and ran it through `eval` so that I could update the extension instantly for all users, without waiting for everyone's extensions to update.

From the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#remotely-hosted-code):

> Externalize logic with a remote service—Consider migrating application logic from the extension to a remote web service that your extension can call. (Essentially a form of message passing.) This provides you the ability to keep code private and change the code on demand while avoiding the extra overhead of resubmitting to the Chrome Web Store.

My question is, how can I do this? What exactly does this mean?

Comment: Great question I too want to know this.

Comment: It means you send the data (HTML of the page) to your server, which analyzes it and sends back some info that your content script will use to do something. Evidently it's not as flexible as your original approach and depending on what you do it may make this workaround completely unusable for you.